# Use of 'and' with nouns

Tags: conjunctions

Which one is right & why?

> 1. I manage agriculture and fabrication business.
> 2. I manage agriculture and fabrication businesses.

Also, is an article needed before *agriculture* and *fabrication*?

Comment: It depends what you mean. Do you manage *one* business that deals with both agriculture and fabrication or do you manage *two* businesses, one concerned with agriculture and another concerned with fabrication?

Answer (score 1):

If you manage a *single* business that deals with *both* agriculture and fabrication, then you are managing:

> an agriculture and fabrication business *(singular)*

If you manage *two separate* businesses, one of which deals *only* with agriculture, and the other of which deals *only* with fabrication, then you are managing:

> an agriculture business *and* a *(separate)* fabrication business.

Edit:

I also agree with the comment from @DJClayworth that, if you were managing several businesses that all deal with either agriculture or fabrication or both, in any combination, then you could refer to managing

> agriculture and fabrication businesses. (plural)

Comment: Technically if you ran several businesses that all deal with either agriculture or fabrication or both, in any combination, then you would say "agriculture and fabrication businesses"

Comment: @DJClayworth Thaks. Have amended answer accordingly.

Comment: The second example could be shortened to "an agriculture and a fabrication business."

Comment: @JamesRandom The second example is mean to be two separate businesses.  In my view, your example is ambiguous & *could* refer to a *single* business.